# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Personal Finance & Money breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  3         30
Users destroyed                                 311          0
Users deleted                                     8          0
Users contacted                                   7          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           139      1,917
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               22        387
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         16        680
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                5        469
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                77      3,728
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              363      3,689
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          0
Tag synonyms created                              1          0
Questions unprotected                             1          1
Questions reopened                               18          9
Questions protected                              72        246
Questions migrated                               36          2
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁴                                7      1,384
Questions closed                                658        639
Question flags handled⁴                         459        932
Posts unlocked                                    4         15
Posts undeleted                                  32         59
Posts locked                                     12        305
Posts deleted⁵                                  786      1,819
Posts bumped                                      0      1,322
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                               90          0
Comments flagged                              1,183      1,323
Comments deleted⁶                             3,690      1,913
Comment flags handled                         2,078        428
Answers flagged                                  30      2,851
Answer flags handled                          1,658      1,223
All comments on a post moved to chat             64          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://money.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Thanks for taking the efforts to post the statistics.